# How can I create a function that counts the number of co-occurrences of specific characters in a single unit?

Tags: r, function

I am trying to create a function that will make R able to read each singular unit (ID) and count the number of co-occurrences of specific characters in that unit. 
The dataset is here below:

```
       ID    class  weight
1       1       A       1.0
2       1       A       1.0
3       1       B       1.0
4       2       A       1.0
5       2       B       1.0
6       2       C       1.0
7       3       B       1.0
8       4       B       1.0
9       4       C       1.0
10      4       C       1.0
11      4       D       1.0
12      4       D       1.0
13      5       A       0.9
14      5       B       0.9
15      5       C       0.9
16      5       D       0.9
17      6       B       0.8
18      6       B       0.8
19      7       C       0.7
20      7       C       0.7
21      7       D       0.7
22      7       D       0.7
23      8       C       0.6
24      8       D       0.6
25      9       D       0.5
26      9       E       0.5
27      9       E       0.5
28     10       C       0.4
29     10       C       0.4
30     10       C       0.4
31     10       E       0.4
32     11       A       0.3
33     11       A       0.3
34     11       A       0.3
35     12       A       0.2
36     12       B       0.2
37     12       C       0.2
38     13       B       0.1
39     13       D       0.1
40     13       D       0.1
41     13       E       0.1
42     14       D       1.0
43     14       E       1.0
44     15       B       1.0
45     15       B       1.0
46     15       C       1.0
47     15       C       1.0
48     15       D       1.0
49     16       C       1.0
50     16       D       1.0
51     16       E       1.0
52     16       E       1.0
53     17       B       1.0
54     17       C       1.0
55     17       C       1.0
56     18       D       1.0
57     18       D       1.0
58     18       E       1.0
59     19       E       1.0
60     19       E       1.0
61     20       B       1.0
62     20       D       1.0
63     20       E       1.0
64     20       E       1.0
```

I tried to create a loop function, but I don't know how to correctly specificy the expression. 
R should recognize ID from 1 up to 20, and in each ID count how many times the characters co-occur together. Not only that, each co-occurrence has to be weighted by the specific weight of the ID. 
Any thoughts about generating a loop function?

Some specifics: 
In ID 1 class A and B co-occur two times (first A with B and second A with B), which multiplied by the weight (1) gives a preliminary value of 2. 
The co-occurrence value of A and B should be 4.1 after the entire list is completed by the loop, and that value should be reported in a matrix 5x5 that looks like this:

```
   A   B    C    D    E
A  1   4.1  ..
B 4.1  1    ..
C ..   ..   1
D ..             1
E ..                  1
```

Co-occurrence between identical classes will be just 1.

> dput(data)
>   structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
>   4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 
>   9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 
>   13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
>   17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), 
>       class = c("A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
>       "D", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", 
>       "C", "D", "D", "E", "E", "C", "C", "C", "E", "A", "A", "A", 
>       "A", "B", "C", "B", "D", "D", "E", "D", "E", "B", "B", "C", 
>       "C", "D", "C", "D", "E", "E", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "E", 
>       "E", "E", "B", "D", "E", "E"), weight = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
>       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.8, 0.8, 0.7, 0.7, 
>       0.7, 0.7, 0.6, 0.6, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 
>       0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
>       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
>   -64L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = )
>   gc()
>             used  (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb) max used  (Mb)
>   Ncells 2672851 142.8    4316924 230.6  4316924 230.6
>   Vcells 5761794  44.0   12425324  94.8 29629603 226.1
>   library(data.table)
>   data <- fread("toy.csv")
>   dput(data)
>   structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
>   4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 
>   9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 
>   13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
>   17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), 
>       class = c("A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
>       "D", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", 
>       "C", "D", "D", "E", "E", "C", "C", "C", "E", "A", "A", "A", 
>       "A", "B", "C", "B", "D", "D", "E", "D", "E", "B", "B", "C", 
>       "C", "D", "C", "D", "E", "E", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "E", 
>       "E", "E", "B", "D", "E", "E"), weight = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
>       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.8, 0.8, 0.7, 0.7, 
>       0.7, 0.7, 0.6, 0.6, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 
>       0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
>       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
>   -64L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = )

Comment: `dput(mat)` does not match your first data frame. Was this intentional? Can you `dput` the one at the top of your post?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. My brain was fried when I posted it. It is now the correct version.

Comment: The syntax of your new `dput` has some issues, but selecting the trailing `structure` seems to replicate your data

Comment: How is it counted if say, for `id = n`, we have `c("A", "A", "B", "B")`. Is this counted as 4 or 2, or ...?

Comment: 4 would be what I am looking for.

Comment: Both solutions that I upvoted are equally great! I opted for Marian's one because the code returns 0s instead of NAs. Good job!

Comment: I edited my answer to have 0s. You should also check out ```xtabs()``` for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

## Data

```
data <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), class = c("A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "C", "D", "D", "E", "E", "C", "C", "C", "E", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "B", "D", "D", "E", "D", "E", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "C", "D", "E", "E", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "B", "D", "E", "E"), weight = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.8, 0.8, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.6, 0.6, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -64L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")) %>% as_tibble()
```

## Main

Create a "count" data frame:

```
(df <- data %>%
  count(ID, class, weight) %>%
  spread(class, n, fill = 0))
```

Get all combinations of classes:

```
eg <- expand.grid(unique(data$class), unique(data$class), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Make a tibble with the pairs and weighted counts:

```
final <- map2(
  eg$Var1,
  eg$Var2,
  ~ df %>% select(.x, .y, weight) %>% 
    mutate(counts = !!sym(.x) * !!sym(.y)) %>%
    mutate(wt_counts = counts * weight) %>%
    select(wt_counts) %>%
    sum() %>%
    tibble(Var1 = .x, Var2 = .y, wt_count = .)
)
```

Convert to a matrix:

```
finalmatrix <- bind_rows(final) %>%
  mutate(wt_count = ifelse(Var1 == Var2, 1, wt_count)) %>%
  spread(Var2, wt_count) %>%
  select(-Var1) %>%
  as.matrix()
```

Finally, set names:

```
row.names(finalmatrix) <- colnames(finalmatrix)
```

## Result

```
> finalmatrix
    A    B    C    D   E
A 1.0  4.1  2.1  0.9 0.0
B 4.1  1.0 10.1  6.1 2.1
C 2.1 10.1  1.0 11.3 3.2
D 0.9  6.1 11.3  1.0 8.2
E 0.0  2.1  3.2  8.2 1.0
```

## Note

I personally don't like how long my solution was and I couldn't see a way around using `rlang` stuff (`!!sym()`), but it works nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

Modified to match @Marian Minar's answer. Also added a `tidyverse` solution which is the fastest of the three methods for this small dataset.

**Tidyverse**:

```
  mat_ans_2 <- DF%>%
    count(ID, class, weight)%>%
    inner_join(., ., by = 'ID')%>%
    filter(class.x != class.y)%>%
    group_by(class.x, class.y)%>%
    summarize(co_occur = sum(weight.x * n.x * n.y))%>%
    spread(key = 'class.x', value = 'co_occur', fill = 0L)%>%
    column_to_rownames('class.y')%>%
    as.matrix()

  diag(mat_ans_2) <- 1L
```

**data.table** - slower on this dataset

```
dt <- as.data.table(DF)[, .N, by = .(ID, class, weight)]

dt2 <- dt[dt, on = 'ID', .(class, i.class, weight, N, i.N), by = .EACHI, allow.cartesian = T
          ][class != i.class, .(co_occur = sum(weight * N * i.N)), by = .(class, i.class)]

dt3 <- dcast(dt2, class ~ i.class, fill = 0, value.var = 'co_occur')

mat_ans <- as.matrix(dt3[,-1])

rownames(mat_ans) = colnames(mat_ans)
diag(mat_ans) <- 1L
```

And here's a bonus way using `xtabs`

```
dt <- setkey(as.data.table(DF)[, .N, by = .(ID, class, weight)], ID)

dt_mat <- xtabs(co_occur ~ i.class + class,
                data = dt[dt, .(class, i.class, co_occur = weight*N*i.N), allow.cartesian = T]
                )

diag(dt_mat) <- 1L
```

**Performance:**

```
Unit: milliseconds
        expr     min        lq       mean    median       uq      max neval
     cole_dt  9.7538  10.36345  10.966212  10.84040  11.1854  15.8167   100
   cole_tidy  5.5976   5.79765   6.221044   5.96675   6.1522  10.0465   100
  cole_xtabs  6.2134   6.65480   7.062921   6.94780   7.2503  13.9981   100
 marian_tidy 95.9504 100.08345 103.244376 101.95380 104.7970 125.7495   100
```

**Data:**

```
DF <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L)
                     , class = c("A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "C", "D", "D", "E", "E", "C", "C", "C", "E", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "B", "D", "D", "E", "D", "E", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "C", "D", "E", "E", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "B", "D", "E", "E")
                     , weight = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.8, 0.8, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.6, 0.6, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))
                , row.names = c(NA, -64L)
                , class = c("data.table", "data.frame")
)
```

Comment: Cole, I think you are right: ID 15 has a total of four (4) co-occurrences of B and C, meaning the weighted count should be 4. If yours does compute to 2, that would explain my 10.1 and your 8.1 in the results. I clarified this situation in a comment to the OP, who explained that the situation seen in ID 15 means that B and C co-occur 4 times (my long-a** way of saying I think I'm right :-)).

Comment: Yep, you had the right approach. I modified my answer and added a different ```tidyverse``` method.

Comment: Nice work and comparison, I hope OP will chime soon and let us know what he thinks.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried shorting Marian's solution but have only gotten through the first two parts. It uses `data.table` which it appears you are already using.

```r
dt <- data[, `:=` (Count = .N), by = list(ID, class)] %>%
  dcast(., ID + weight ~ class, value.var = "Count")

eg.dt <- merge(unique(data$class), unique(data$class), all = TRUE) %>%
  setnames(., c("x", "y"), c("Var1", "Var2"))
```

Not a big reduction in the code. If I come up with more I'll update.